# Kotlin - Extract value from function

Tags: kotlin, spinner

I'm working about a Kotlin code and I need to use a value that is create inside a function. I share my code:

```
        val Myspinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        if (Myspinner!= null) {
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pulsatil)
            Myspinner.adapter = adapter
        }

        Myspinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            //val pulsatil2 = Myspinner.selectedItem.toString()
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {TODO("not implemented")}
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val Spinnervalue: String = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            }
        }

val MyArrayList: MutableList<Spinnervalue> = ArrayList()
```

Then I want to add "Spinnervalue" to "MyArrayList". I tried to create "Myfinalvalue" like a global value of the class, but it not works.

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you need to be able to access your array anywhere in the class so "MyArrayList" has to be global.
Second, here:

```
val MyArrayList: MutableList<Spinnervalue> = ArrayList()
```

you have passed "Spinnervalue" as the type for your arraylist while the type of value you are adding to your arraylist is actually a String. so your final code in the activity should look like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val myArrayList = arrayListOf<String>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val Myspinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)
    if (Myspinner!= null) {
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pulsatil)
        Myspinner.adapter = adapter
    }

    Myspinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        //val pulsatil2 = Myspinner.selectedItem.toString()
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {TODO("not implemented")}
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            val Spinnervalue: String = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            myArrayList.add(Spinnervalue)
        }
    }
}
```

make your arraylist at the top and then add your value inside the onItemSelected function just like the code I posted.